# What is the possibility of using the ionosphere or van Allen belts as a source of propellant for ion engines especially for orbital station keeping?

Tags: electromagnetism, astronomy, astrophysics

Just like how a jet engine uses the air it moves through to propel it self forward.
In this case energy for ionizing the propellant won't be needed because we already have ions.
How viable is my proposal?

Comment: The particle density in the Van Allen belts is far lower than in the best vacuum on Earth... not much to work with, unless you can get the Bussard collector of the USS Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment above, regarding the particle densities involved, if you read through this Wikipedia article, [Van Allen Belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt), you will see that there are two main problems with the idea.

1. Despite the low particle density, the Van Allen Belts are not places that you want your spacecraft to travel through, as the high energy radiation involved in these regions will likely damage electronics, unless the spaceprobe is hardened against them.

From Wikipedia:

> The Hubble Space Telescope, among other satellites, often has its sensors turned off when passing through regions of intense radiation.

2. Keeping the particles confined within the probe until you reach an area of neutral space would require a lot of energy, it's probably easier and cheaper to build your own ion thruster from scratch, rather than scooping up low density charged particles.